# Coldfusion: attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, coldfusion, dereference

Below is the code for the array that I am trying to build. I am building a table based on the array that consist of a Skill ID (SKID), Priority, and Default Rating. I cannot find what is wrong with my array but whenever I open the page I get the following Error:

"You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members."

Thank you.

```
<cfloop query="DisplayLearningPathOne">
    <cfset BlankDocumentArray[CurrentRow][1]= SKID>
    <cfset BlankDocumentArray[CurrentRow][2]= Priority>
    <cfset BlankDocumentArray[CurrentRow][3]= Default_Rating>
</cfloop>

<cfset Total_Records = BlankDocumentArray.RecordCount>
 <cfloop index="Counter" from=1 to="#arraylen(Total_Records)#">
    <cfoutput>
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>Skill_ID</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Default_Rating</th>
   </tr>

   <tr>
        <td>#BlankDocument[Counter][1]#,</td>
        <td>#BlankDocument[Counter][2]#,</td>
        <td>#BlankDocument[Counter][3]#,</td>
  </tr>

  </table>
  </cfoutput>


 </cfloop>
```

Comment: Is there more to this code than we are seeing? Why would you create an array to loop through instead of just using `<cfoutput query="DisplayLearningPathOne">` around your row

Comment: The error message will also be telling you the precise line of code that is erroring, and the exact expression that is erroring, does it not? Could you pls include that? Where are you declaring `BlankDocumentArray` and `BlankDocument`? Did you dump out the variable it is saying is a scalar value, and check what it contains?

Answer (score 6):

The error is from this line:

> <cfset Total_Records = BlankDocumentArray.RecordCount>

blankdocumentsarray is not a query, and has no `recordCount` property. You need to check the `ArrayLen` as you do in the following line.

Comment: The error I get now is "Object of type class java.lang.Integer cannot be used as an array" I made the appropriate changes that you suggested.

Comment: Then either you are doing something different than what was suggested above or are using code we cannot see. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21942713/edit) to append the actual code throwing that error.

Comment: If you are still looping over the query to create an array...you are doing it wrong...very...very...wrong.

Comment: I've heard of turning array's into queries but never the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it be easier to do :

```
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>Skill_ID</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Default_Rating</th>
   </tr>
   <cfoutput query="DisplayLearningPathOne">
   <tr>
        <td>#BlankDocument.skid#</td>
        <td>#BlankDocument.priority#</td>
        <td>#BlankDocument.default_rating#</td>
  </tr>
  </cfoutput>
  </table>
```

Comment: No, because I need to pass multiple rows, and not everyone will have the same amount of rows.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do (in general terms)? As Lance and others have implied, it is possible there may be a simpler method than using arrays.

Comment: As of right now it is a test. I need to pass each row into a table in the database, and I am testing an array because I need a structured way to store each Skill ID to the proper Priority and Rating

Comment: You goal still is not clear. Passing data from where? From `<form>` inputs, from one db table to another, ...? Because there are simpler ways to handle both of those scenarios, than pulling data into an intermediary array.

Comment: Nothing you have said indicates that you actually need an array.

Comment: I love when someone asks a question about doing something wonky, and when they get told its wonky, they get all indignant - and by 'love', I actually mean 'loathe'